# jQuery countdown running when it's paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm using Keith Wood's jQuery Countdown timer. http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

What I want to achieve is a countup with stop and resume buttons, and controls to add and subtract minutes and seconds:

I create a countup (from 0 to 60 minutes) and pause it right away, like this:

```
$('#contador_tiempo').countdown({
    since: 0,
    format: 'MS',
    layout: '{mnn}{sep}{snn}'
});

$('#contador_tiempo').countdown('pause');
```

But it seems that it's still running in the background. When I click the buttons to add or subtract, the functions do the operations on top of that background counter, not the displayed counter.

Full code on JSFiddle, with the behaviour reproduced:

http://jsfiddle.net/J2XHm/4/

(Play a bit with the controls and you will see that it keeps counting although it's paused.)

Comment: Looks like `pause` and `getTimes` are not playing along with each other. `getTimes` seems to continusly keep updating. When removing all of the code in one of the click events and only adding `$('#contador_tiempo').countdown('getTimes')` you can see the array of digits continusly increasing even though you paused it at the start. It might be a bug. The documentation for `pause` states: `No onTick or onExpiry events are triggered while the countdown is paused.` Which would inidcate it should not count any times. I would contact the author of the plug-in to get information on that.

Comment: Just to add, you should propably contact the author of a plug-in first before asking on SO or at least at the same time. You might get a workaround on SO but the Author could be telling you what you doing wrong or appreaciate a bug being pointed out and fix it rather than you ending up with a hacky workaround.

Comment: I've sent him an email with this question, so he can look at it. I hope we can sort this out! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've contancted him in the past, but I think that having this public will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is good information for future users. I +1 ed your question anyway already cause it is not obvious why it behaves like that and therefore I think it is a good question in general. Hopefully the Author knows what going on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a bug in the 'getTimes' command - it recalculates when paused. I'll make the correction in the next release (1.6.2) but in the meantime you can change the _getTimesPlugin function:

```
_getTimesPlugin: function(target) {
    var inst = $.data(target, this.propertyName);
    return (!inst ? null : (inst._hold == 'pause' ? inst._savePeriods : (!inst._hold ? inst._periods :
        this._calculatePeriods(inst, inst._show, inst.options.significant, new Date()))));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept lightweight code, i.e. without using the jQuery countdown timer, the following might help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/web/JavaScript/jQuery/jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var countUpSeconds = 0;
    var interval = null;
    function displayTime() {
          $("#timeContainer").text(format(Math.floor(countUpSeconds/60))+":"+format(countUpSeconds%60));
    }
    function playStop() {
        if(interval) {interval=window.clearInterval(interval);}
        else {interval = window.setInterval(countUp, 1000);}
    }
    function countUp() {
        ++countUpSeconds;
        if(countUpSeconds >= 3600) {/* do something when countup is reached*/}
        displayTime();
    }
    function format(s) {return s<10 ? "0"+s : s;}
    $(function() {
        displayTime();
        $("#playStop").on("click", function () { playStop(); } );
        $("#addMin").on("click", function () { countUpSeconds += 60; displayTime(); } );
        $("#subMin").on("click", function () { countUpSeconds = Math.max(0, countUpSeconds-60); displayTime(); } );
        $("#addSec").on("click", function () { countUpSeconds += 1; displayTime(); } );
        $("#subSec").on("click", function () { countUpSeconds = Math.max(0, countUpSeconds-1); displayTime(); } );

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="timeContainer"></div>
<button id="playStop">Play/Stop</button>
<button id="addMin">+1 minute</button>
<button id="subMin">-1 minute</button>
<button id="addSec">+1 second</button>
<button id="subSec">-1 second</button>
</body>
</html>
```